# Do not expire cached item in IMemoryCache implementation

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Since `IMemoryCache` does not give too much info about the cached items I was thinking to implement something custom in order to keep some data about items in the cache like the `key`, `AbsoluteExpiration` properties etc.

Here is my implementation of `IMemoryCache`:

```
public class MemoryCacheService : IMemoryCache
{
    private readonly MemoryCache _memoryCache;
    private readonly List<CacheItemRelevantData> _allKeys;
    private readonly string AllKeys = "___All__Keys___";
    public MemoryCacheService()
    {
        _memoryCache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
        _allKeys = new List<CacheItemRelevantData>();
        _memoryCache.Set(AllKeys, _allKeys, new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
        {
            AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.MaxValue
        });
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _memoryCache.Dispose();
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(object key, out object value)
    {
        return _memoryCache.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    public ICacheEntry CreateEntry(object key)
    {
        var entry = _memoryCache.CreateEntry(key);
        entry.RegisterPostEvictionCallback((o, v, reason, state) =>
        {
            if (reason.In(EvictionReason.Capacity, EvictionReason.Expired, EvictionReason.TokenExpired))
            {
                var item = _allKeys.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.ToString() == o.ToString());
                if (item != null)
                {
                    _allKeys.Remove(item);
                }
            }
        });
        if (!_allKeys.Select(x => x.Key).Contains(key))
        {
            _allKeys.Add(new CacheItemRelevantData
            {
                Key = entry.Key,
                AbsoluteExpiration = entry.AbsoluteExpiration,
                Priority = entry.Priority,
                AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = entry.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow,
                Size = entry.Size
            });
        }
        return entry;
    }

    public void Remove(object key)
    {
        var entry = _allKeys.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.ToString() == key.ToString());
        if (entry != null)
        {
            _allKeys.Remove(entry);
        }

        _memoryCache.Remove(key);
    }
}
```

But since `_allKeys` is created to store the relevant data about cached items I dont want it to expire.

Is there any way to set expire time to none or something similar and the `_allKeys` list will remain in cache forever ?

Comment: Why would _allKeys expire? It doesn't look like a part of cache...

Comment: @AlexRiabov what do u mean its not part of the cache ? Please take a look at constructor where i set it in the cache

Comment: @AlexRiabov actually now that I am thinking I could make it static and not set it in the cache at all, I guess there is no issue with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my case I could easily solve the problem because the `IMemoryService` was configured as scoped service and that means `_allKeys` variable is persisting in memory as far `IMemoryService` instance(until the iis is restarted or something). For non-scoped service I did not find a proper solution but I think `IMemoryCache` service should always be a scoped service(there is no real case to have it configured differently -**maybe!!**)